# Weird error with glibc on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, glibc

I have a weird issue with some servers that I manage at work.. We use Katello/Satellite 6 to manage our repos/pkgs and subscribe our servers to it. In the Katello Web UI it says that `glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64` and `glibc-common-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64` is an applicable update on the system, I'll then click to update and it'll say successful.. however nothing happens and Katello still shows me that it's an applicable update.

If I ssh to the server itself and try and do a `yum install glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64` it says no package found. This is on a CentOS 6.10 box. Could I potentially be missing a repo which has this package? Currently I am syncing cents6 extras, os, updates, and epel6 repos.

We have some other packages such as nscd which rely on the latest glibc as a dependency as well so I'm just super curious why this is happening.

Comment: OK `glibc` is the most important library in OS and any updates to it (what you ask about) will surely be available in `updates` official repo.

Comment: So in my upstream repo of http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/ has the package `glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64`. If that's the case how come doing a yum install of glibc doesnt let me install the latest version?

Comment: What do your logfiles say?

Comment: What logfiles would I look at in this case? I don't think there's any actual errors as opposed to for whatever reason yum can't see glib-212 from any of my repos